# Linux rsync without recursive folders

Tags: linux, rsync

I have a hierarchy of folders and want to rsync the file contents of one to another.

So a simple rsync dirA to dirB

However without the recursive element it does not include the files in the folder.

```
dave:/tmp# mkdir dirA
dave:/tmp# mkdir dirB
dave:/tmp# touch dirA/tmp.txt
dave:/tmp# rsync --stats dirA/ dirB/
skipping directory .

Number of files: 0
Number of files transferred: 0
```

I can do

```
dave:/tmp# rsync --stats dirA/* dirB/

Number of files: 1
Number of files transferred: 1
```

However if there are tens of thousands of files, the argument list might become too long.

It seems a fairly simple operation to sync the contents of two folders, without sub folders, however I am clearly missing something?

Comment: Try 'rsync --stats dirA dirB' (without / ).

Comment: Did you tried `--exlude` with something like `rsync -r --exclude='*/*' SRC/ DEST/`? You can avoid that the shell expands the parameter too..

Comment: Or this (found in Internet): rsync -avc --exclude "*/" ./source/* ./destination/

Comment: The first option doesn't work, tried without /

Comment: having to specify excludes for what seems such a normal task seemed overkill and made me think I was missing something...

Comment: rsync -r--exclude "/" ./source/ ./destination/ only works with -r which means you are saying "do recursive, and exclude folders".  that seems counter-intuitive. or, a hack.  the rsync avc works because a is archive mode.  However I don't really want to use archive mode, so, again, just surprised there's no normal way to do sync A/ B/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this help? Option -d and -m of the man-page:

```
   -d, --dirs                  transfer directories without recursing 
   -m, --prune-empty-dirs      prune empty directory chains from file-list
```

and run ...

```
mkdir dirA
mkdir dirB
mkdir dirA/dirAA
touch dirA/fileA
touch dirA/dirAA/fileAA
rsync --stats -dm dirA/ dirB/
```

Output:

```
Number of files: 3 (reg: 1, dir: 2)
Number of created files: 1 (reg: 1)
Number of deleted files: 0
Number of regular files transferred: 1
Total file size: 0 bytes
Total transferred file size: 0 bytes
Literal data: 0 bytes
Matched data: 0 bytes
File list size: 0
File list generation time: 0.001 seconds
File list transfer time: 0.000 seconds
Total bytes sent: 123
Total bytes received: 31
```

Result:

```
ls dirB
fileA
```

Comment: Perfect!  This was able to traverse a massive file structure at only the first dir level with ease.